# "I can't get over the way your face looks"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, phrasal-verbs

Two old friends run into each other after long time. Now one of them's saying to another:

> I can't **get over** the way your face looks.

What does that mean? In particular, what does **get over** mean here?

Comment: Hmm, I couldn't find an appropriate definition [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/get+over), and I'm having a hard time thinking of how to explain it.

Comment: @Ben Kovitz Could it be " to forget"

Comment: Possibly it means that "your face looks way more different than it was. And I don't get how it's changed." Or, it could mean that "I'll never forget what your face looks like". I came along these results with "Pythagorical" thinking! :-)

Comment: Consider: "7. To come to understand or no longer be surprised by something. Used in the negative: *I can't get over the fact that he's still living in that awful apartment.*" [Idioms by The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+over)

Comment: @F.E. That's the right answer!

Answer (score 9):

The phrasal verb *get over* means *recover from*. It's often used in the context of overcoming illness, injury, or a painful experience, but I like the way this [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/get-over) dictionary defines it:

> **get over** (*phrasal verb*) recover from (an ailment or an upsetting or startling experience): *‘the trip will help him get over Sal’s death’*

In this case, the person is simply surprised by his old friend's face. We don't know why (context doesn't say), but we can make some guesses:

> I can't get over the way your face looks – you look so young! (*surprise*)
>
> I can't get over the way your face looks – your wife's death must have been hard on you. (*empathy*)
>
> I can't get over the way your face looks – where is that face painting booth? (*laughter*)

Any of those three are possible, but I suspect it would be the first. It mirrors what one person  wrote in an [advertisement](http://diabetesfreenow.com/one-health-beauty-product/) for a nutrition product:

> Recently I was at a gathering, and was in the company of a man I'd worked with in 2003 and 2004. 
> I noticed he kept watching me. Finally I went over to him, extended my hand and introduced myself. 
> He said, “I know who you are, ***I just can’t get over how you look***.  You look twenty years younger.”

Answer (score 6):

*I can't get over* something means you've become fixated on it, preoccupied with it, or even mildly obsessed with it.

Saying *I can't get over your face* means that I'm fixated on your face, probably either because I find it very attractive or very unattractive.

Comment: A close friend wouldn't know the other one unattractively impossible to forget!